# Search and filter JSON list of friends returned by facebook

Tags: jquery, json, search

I am trying to get friends of a logged facebook user. I use fql, and I want to update the list for every letter typed in search box. I am doing this live in fql and this works OK.

I happened to read that it is better to read all friends at once and then search the JSON object.

For an array

```
[{"uid":"1235","name":"user1_abcde","picture":"picurl"},
 {"uid":"1237","name":"user2_abcde","picture":"picur2"},
 {"uid":"1289","name":"user3_agere","picture":"picur3"}
]
```

How can I sort, to get results in an array for a search string (eg: "de") PARTIALLY matching name field to return

```
 [{"uid":"1235","name":"user1_abcde","picture":"picurl"},
   {"uid":"1237","name":"user2_abcde","picture":"picur2"}
  ]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to parse json and then search using regex.

```
function search(json, regex) {
    var result = [];
    $.each(JSON.parse(json), function(i, row) {
       if (row.name.match(regex)) {
          result.push(row);
       }
    });
    return result;
}
```

and you can use that function to search for de using `search(json, /de/)`

Comment: IMO regex is a bit of an overkill if OP only needs to match substring.

Comment: @jcubic can you hint on how to write the regex expression for this?

Comment: @aVC for de `/de/` if you what to search ending as de you can use `/de$/`

Comment: @pawel regex is great because he can do more complex things in the future, and `"de"` was just example. Regex is more general,

Comment: @aVC if you have a string (say, user input) and need to find matching elements using regex you first need to construct a regex from string, i.e. `regex = new RegExp( string );`

Comment: @pawel thanks for tht useful comment, I got the idea, and tweaked it to fit my app.

Answer (score 0):

```
var searchFriend = function( str ){
    /* make search case-insensitive */
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    /* assuming `friendsArray` is your cached JSON response */
    return friendsArray.filter( 
        function( i ){ return (i['name'].toLowerCase().indexOf( str ) > -1) }
    );
}
```

[Array.filter at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)